# how to store gridview contents into database table

Tags: c#

I Have a gridview with just one column. I have written code like

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString); 
        con.Open();

        for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
       {
            string Users = GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Text;

            string strQuery = "insert into Table1 (FileName, DateTimeUploaded, Type, Username)" +
            " values(@FileName, @DateTimeUploaded, @Type, @Username)";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strQuery);

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FileName", datalink);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Type", ext);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateTimeUploaded", DateTime.Now);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", Users);

            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.Connection = con;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

       }
        con.Close();
        con.Dispose();

          }
```

If this gridview has 2 rows, then the first row is stored in database twice. If gridview has 3 rows then the first row is stored thrice. How can I solve this?

Comment: You might want to do a search on ".Net data binding" before doing too much more.  You may find something that does everything you want for you...

Comment: You should check for the "e.ItemType" in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Explanation:**

You are inserting your data into the database inside your GridView's `RowDataBound` event - this is executing every time a DataRow is being bound! This, along with the fact that you're looping accross every row *each* time using:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)  { // inserting record from each row }
```

means your rows are going to be inserted more than once as more rows are bound. You need to remove your `for` loop, and use `e.Row.Cells[0]` instead to reference and insert just the currently bound row data.

```
 string Users = e.Row.Cells[0].Text;
```

You probably also want to check for only DataRows so your operations don't occur on footer/header rows etc.

**New Code:**

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e) 
{ 
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString);  
        con.Open(); 

        string Users = e.Row.Cells[0].Text; // current row being bound

        string strQuery = "insert into Table1 (FileName, DateTimeUploaded, Type, Username)" + 
        " values(@FileName, @DateTimeUploaded, @Type, @Username)"; 
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strQuery); 

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FileName", datalink); 
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Type", ext); 
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateTimeUploaded", DateTime.Now); 
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", Users); 

        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text; 
        cmd.Connection = con; 
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); 

        con.Close(); 
        con.Dispose(); 
     }
 }
```